# disable Input submit form on enter but enter values on enter

Tags: php, html, forms, button, submit

I have The Following lines of code, when I attempt to enter an amount in the input division and hit enter, it automatically submits the form,

I need the input to change the amount when i Hit enter without submitting the form automatically only when i click on the submit button

how do I change My Lines Of code?

```
<input id="stake" type ="number" name="stake[]" value="5">

<input class="bet1" type="submit" name="submit" value="Bet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an onkeyup listener to the number input.

Return false if the keyCode on the event is 13, which is the code for the enter key.

```
<input id="stake" type ="number" name="stake[]" value="5" onkeypress="preventSubmissionOnEnter(event)">

<script>
function preventSubmissionOnEnter(e) {
   if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This code is still not working, its still submitting on enter

Comment: I updated my answer with properly working code

Comment: With the new code there is still a problem now I cannot enter my stake amount with enter key,I need it to enter and change the stake amount without submitting the whole form

Comment: Can you please clarify what is is you want to happen when the enter key is pressed when focused on the "stake" input?

Comment: I need it to change amount after hitting the enter key, for example if there is 5 in the input box, I click on it, type 25 hit enter and it changes the amount to 25 but it should not submit the form

Comment: What else are you trying to change?
If you type in 25 then it has already changed to 25.
Is there another DOM element you are trying to update?
Or do you mean the value attribute on the element itself?

Comment: It will change to 25 but my java script calculations will not trigger before hitting enter or click anywhere outside the input box, Im trying to hit enter and it triggers the calculations but without submitting the form

Comment: So call your calculations on the same onkeypress listener I've added my function to.
You have not provided your calculations so without more details I cannot help you any further.